# Привязка onclick работает не верно

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привязка onclick работает не верно.

У меня есть такой код:

```
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function (e) {
  console.log('Add to cart', e)
  $(this).toggleClass('add-to-cart')
  $(this).addClass('remove-from-cart')
  $(this).text('Удалить')
})

$('.remove-from-cart').on('click', function (e) {
  console.log('Remove from cart', e)
  $(this).toggleClass('remove-from-cart')
  $(this).addClass('add-to-cart')
  $(this).text('Добавлено')
 })
```

При клике на .add-to-cart всё отлично отрабатывает, класс меняется.
[image: Это до клика]
[image: После клика]

Теперь после клика на .remove-from-cart, работает код, который привязан на .add-to-cart, почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

событие привязывается не к классу, а к элементу DOM. Классом вы только фильтруете элементы, к которым привязывается обработчик события. поэтому единожды привязав при старте событие добавления на кнопку, оно так и останется там висеть.

у вас есть по сути 3 варианта действий:

- сделать две кнопки. скрывать или показывать нужную вместо смены классов
- Использовать одну кнопку, но добавить data-атрибут, который будет определять действие, и в обработчике клика ориентироваться на него.
- добавить событие на подходящий родительский элемент.

  ```
  $(".some-parent").on('click', '.add-to-cart', func1)  
                   .on('click', '.remove-from-cart', func2)`
  ```